# Android Play background sound

Tags: android

I am going to create call record application, There I need to play minute and recording notification sound. It should here to caller and receiver two parties. Is there any good example for such application?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

> I am going to create call record application

That is not possible on Android. Android SDK applications do not have access to the in-call audio.